# How to multiply "5x3" string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How may I multiply this string: "5x3" and get the total as integer?

Answer (score 5):

My philosophy tends to be "get it into a data structure, use the great tools we have for working with data structures, then convert back if necessary".

```
"5x3".split('x').map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*)
```

Comment: Reduce didn't added to Enumerable until 1.8.7.
if ruby < 1.8.7, just replace, reduce to inject

"5x3".split('x').map(&:to_i).inject(&:*)

Comment: I don't think you need `&` for inject, unlike other enumerables.

Comment: @Mr. Black: 1.9.2 is the latest ruby that most people should be using. If you are are not, you should be using REE at least, and if you are not on 1.8.7 you should upgrade to that. There is no real reason to be using older versions of ruby then that

Answer (score 3):

There are two safe ways of doing this: using eval with `$SAFE` set to 1 or higher (how high depends on your application), or use a dedicated maths parser. I recommend the second method (much harder to go wrong with that), only use the eval method if you need more than basic arithmetic evaluation.

To do this, install the `expression_parser` gem with `gem install expression_parser`.  Then you can use the the following code to eval a math expression:

```
require 'expression_parser'
parser = ExpressionParser::Parser.new
p p.parse("5 * 3")
```

This will print out `15.0`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a parser. With respect to using $SAFE: it's worthwhile mentioning it, but I don't think all implementations of Ruby implement `$SAFE` fully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
eval("5x3".gsub("x","*"))
```

or if you're a normal paranoid:

```
eval(str.gsub('x','*').gsub(/[^\d+*-\/]/,''))
```

Comment: **Be careful** with `eval`, as slightly mischievous users will give input like `"5x3; \`rm some_important_file\`"`. Ooops.

Comment: Wow. It really is a jungle out there.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of trying to sanitize your input (at least a little), here is my suggestion:

```
def multiply_from_string(string)
  string.split('x').map { |number| number.to_i }.inject(&:*)
end
```

Still, kind of ridiculous.