# How to split string into array as integers

Tags: ruby

Given something like this

```
@grid = "4x3".split("x")
```

The current result is an array of strings "4","3"

Is there any shortcut to split it directly to integers?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > left, right =  "4x3".split("x").map(&:to_i)
 => [4, 3] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > left
 => 4 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > right
 => 3
```

Call map on the resulting array to convert to integers, and assign each value to left and right, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

```
"4x3".split("x").map(&:to_i)
```

if you don't wan to be too strict,

```
"4x3".split("x").map {|i| Integer(i) }
```

if you want to throw exceptions if the numbers don't look like integers (say, "koi4xfish")

Answer (score 3):

```
>> "4x3".split("x").map(&:to_i)
=> [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seeing if the expression parser mentioned in [an answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574918/how-to-multiply-5x3-string-in-ruby/5575074#5575074) would allow you to do this?