# Regex to constrain "3x2" string

Tags: ruby, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split string into array as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575035/how-to-split-string-into-array-as-integers)

I have a "3x2" string.

How can I constrain with regex to cover these validations:

1. validate presence of first number
2. validates that there's a "x" and only one.
3. validate the presence of the second number.

Comment: Related questions by the same OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575035/how-to-split-string-into-array-as-integers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574918/how-to-multiply-5x3-string-in-ruby

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex?

Comment: How would you do it instead Andrew?

Comment: It would be easier to look at a regex reference than ask a question here. Might I suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html and then http://regexpal.com/.

Comment: @Martin: It was suggested in an answer to a previous question by you that you may want to use the expression parser gem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574918/how-to-multiply-5x3-string-in-ruby/5575074#5575074 . I assume you've read the answers to the previous questions you've asked, right?

Comment: @Andrew, the OP likes this question, he's OWNING it.

Comment: -1 for asking what's basically the same question three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
three_by_two = /\A\d{3}x\d{2}\z/
if my_str =~ three_by_two
```

Decoded:

- Start at the beginning of the string
- 3 digits
- a literal `x`
- 2 digits
- The end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
/\dx\d/
```

And then some more characters to make my answer long enough.

Comment: not familiar with ruby, but isn't `\d` going to result in rejecting cases where your number is more than 1 digit long?  I'd consider using kleene closure.

Comment: How should it be instead? Numbers can be one or more digit long.

Comment: @Martin: Did you try researching how to match for multiple characters in regular expressions?

Comment: @Marin - That should be in your question, but it's \d+x\d+. Or see zobgib's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+x[0-9]+
```

Will match number of any length x number of any length

When you say 3x2 you mean a 3 digit number x 2 digit number use

```
[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: Note that `[0-9]` is better written as `\d` (less characters to type, read, and more clear about the intent).

Comment: I'm so tempted to down vote the answer because it misses the obvious use of the `\d` character class, but I'm feeling charitable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like:

```
/\A\d+x\d+\Z/
```

Comment: Remember that in Ruby `^/$` matches the start/end of line, not start/end of string.